# Как сделать random на Kivy, для Label, при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, kivy

Делаю программу, "Правда или действие", и столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня не работает random, выбивает NameError: name 'random' is not defined, (извините если не правильно написал ошибку). Если что, Пишу на Kivy, в python вместе с Builder.

Вот код:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.config import Config

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

import random

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")
Config.set("graphics", "width", "500")
Config.set("graphics", "height", "850")

category6 = [("Пригни 10 раз"), ("Закрой глаза")]
ListCategory6 = len(category6)

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:
            "vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: [30]
        Button:
            text: "Начать игру'
            background_color: [5, 1.7, 1, 5]
            size_hint: [1, 0.1]
            font_size: 50
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:
            "vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: [30]
        Button:
            text: 'Назад'
            size_hint: [1, 0.6]
            background_color: [5, 1, 1, 5]
            on_press: root.manager.current = "menu"
        Label:
            text: "Выбери возрастную категорию"
            size_hint: [1, 0.5]
            font_size: 35
        Button:
            text: "6+"
            background_color: [2.3, 0.1, 4, 1]
            font_size: 40
            on_press: root.manager.current = "Six"

<SixScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "top"
        padding: [25]
        Button:
            text: "Назад"
            background_color: [5, 1, 1, 5]
            size_hint: [1, 0.07]
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "bottom"
        padding: [25]
        Button:
            text: "Получить Задание"
            background_color: [0, 1.7, 0, 1]
            size_hint: [1, 0.07]
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'SixLabel'
        Label:
            text: "Задания 6+"
            font_size: 50

<SixLabel>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x:
            "center"
        anchor_y:
            "top"
        padding: [25]
        Button:
            text: "Назад"
            size_hint: [1, 0.07]
            background_color: [5, 1, 1, 5]
            on_press: root.manager.current = "Six"
        Label:
            text: random.randrange(0, ListCategory6)            
""")

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SixScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SixLabel(Screen):
    pass

class randsix(Screen):
    pass

game = ScreenManager()
game.add_widget(MenuScreen(name = 'menu'))
game.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name = 'settings'))

game.add_widget(SixScreen(name = "Six"))

game.add_widget(SixLabel(name = "SixLabel"))

class PlayPutannyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return game

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PlayPutannyApp().run()
```

Comment: может внутри этого buildera random не работает,попробуйте вне этой функции сначала получить число а потом просто переменной передать значение в text

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

.py

```
import random
category6 = [("Пригни 10 раз"), ("Закрой глаза")]
....
class SixLabel(Screen):
    def random_task(self):
        return str(random.choice(category6))
```

.kv

```
<SixLabel>:
    ....
    Label:
        text: root.random_task()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Только оно почему-то выводит число, а не сам вопрос. Но все равно большое вам спасибо!

Comment: @Яяя Исправил ответ, если я правильно понял, что вам нужно, то так должно сработать

Comment: Спасибо, но я только исправил randint, на choise, и работает, спасибо что помогли, я сейчас убрал окно что которое появляется и сейчас пробую сделать так, чтобы оно выводилось после нажатия на кнопку "Получить задание", но вы очень мне помогли!